# How can I make a TreeView to have its first item selected and expanded at program start?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml, treeview

My TreeView has an XML-Document as Itemssource. It all works fine, but at startup no items are selected. It would be nice if the first TreeViewItem would be selected and expanded.

MyTreeView.items.count gives 0 at startup so i cannot access any treeviewitems.

I tried

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
</Style>
```

but that caused ALL the TreeviewItems to be expanded.

Can somebody help?

Comment: start by doing a simple google search http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode

Comment: @daniele3004 it sure looks better now. Thanks for editing. Especially adding xaml as tag is a good idea.